# Good Books about Large Cardinals

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, textbook-recommendation

I am very new to set theory and have only learned the basics up to cardinal and ordinal arithmetic. I would like to learn about large cardinals and I am reading Thomas Jech's Set Theory. I have read that Kanamori's book is a good resource but I think that one is a bit advanced for me still. Are there any other books out there? Also is there a book that looks at the philosophical aspects of the subject and is less technical?
Thanks:)

Comment: You should learn more about basic set theory, then. Kanamori's book is an excellent reference, and for large cardinals I think it's better than Jech's book. I find his writing style to be easier to read. You should continue learning the basics of set theory, when you can read Kanamori's book then you're in a level sufficient for understanding large cardinals.

Comment: I guess the easiest book on the topic is *Set Theory: An Introduction to Large Cardinals* by Drake.

Comment: Though quite nice, the problem with Drake's book is that it is badly dated. In particular, most large cardinals that are the focus of current research are not developed there, notoriously Woodin cardinals. Kanamori *is* the reference.

Comment: For philosophical aspects, I would suggest to begin with Maddy's two papers on "Believing the axioms", J. Symbolic Logic 53 (1988), no. 2, 481-511 and no. 3, 736-764.

Comment: Hi there. Textbook recommendation questions are usually marked "community wiki" because there is no one correct answer. You can make this change by clicking the "edit" button then checking the "CW" box. In the old version of MathOverflow it was in the lower right, but I'm not sure now. Anyway, it shouldn't be too hard to find. I don't know any good introductory books on Large Cardinals. I learned most of what I know about them from Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories, by Adamek and Rosicky. Might be a bit technical for a starting place, though.

Comment: "The King's Cardinal" by Peter Gwyn. http://www.librarything.com/work/1968903 (Sorry, couldn't resist. I'll get my coat.)

Comment: @Yemon, isn't that a large book about a good cardinal? I was going to suggest http://trove.nla.gov.au/work/32427703?versionId=39414653 along similar lines.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: For my part, my first thought was https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26526452-c-is-for-cardinal …

Comment: @Peter, the Australian edition: https://www.amazon.com/C-Cockatoo-Childrens-Hardcover-Boardbook/product-reviews/0990604012

Answer (score 5):

The question got bumped, and so let me take this opportunity to say that Kanamori's book is definitely the right source for anyone who is interested in entering this fascinating subject. Some time ago, I wrote a review of it, which you can find at:

- [Book review of The Higher Infinite, by Akihiro Kanamori](http://jdh.hamkins.org/bookreviewkanamori/).

If you find his book to be too advanced, then the solution is simply to learn a little more set theory, which you can do by studying Jech's book Set Theory, among others. Much of Kanamori's book, however, is not so technical, and he has a delightful habit of weaving the historical development into the unfolding story. It is a pleasure to read!

Answer (score 2):

There's Rucker's *Infinity and the Mind* (Appendix A in particular), although you may find it a bit basic (plus I don't know if it has been updated since it was written).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend picking up a good text on model theory, in particular Chang/Keislers reference on the subject. I'm in a similar position to you -- I own Kanamori's book but am as of yet unable to unlock the treasures within, however I'm very comfortable with ordinal/cardinal arithmetic as a result of Donald Monk's excellent text on MK class theory.

Other research concerns have prevented me from really digging in to Chang/Keisler as of yet so I can't say this with total certainty, but from the skimming I've done of Kanamori's text it seems like the main ingredient missing for a good, comprehensive reading (in my case) is the toolbox of model theory.

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes?  If I'm incorrect I would enjoy knowing why.